# How to interpolate data by latitudes and longitudes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

I have A dataset that contains unstructured data, latitudes and longitudes

How to interpolate data by inverse distance weighting?

When I use `scipy.griddata`, the points around the 90 degree elevation is not reasonable

Is there any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try plotting it using `plotly`, which gives you interactive plot. You can verify the values over each point in `terrain`.

You can refer below code for details.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Read data from a csv
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patel999jay/Bedford_python/master/bathy_bedford.csv'
z_data = pd.read_csv(url)
# z_data.head() # to see dataframe head
# Read data from a csv
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patel999jay/Bedford_python/master/bathy_bedford.csv'
z_data = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)

z = z_data.values
sh_0, sh_1 = z.shape
x, y = np.linspace(44.66875, 44.74791667, sh_0), np.linspace(-63.69791667, -63.52708333, sh_1) # This is lat and long
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, x=x, y=y,colorscale='Viridis')])
fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=True,
                                  highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True))
fig.update_layout(title='Bedford Basin Elevation',xaxis_title="Latitude", 
                  yaxis_title="Longitude",autosize=False,
                  width=900, height=900, 
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(
                    xaxis_title='Latitude',
                    yaxis_title='Longitude',
                    zaxis_title='Elevation'),
                    margin=dict(r=20, b=10, l=10, t=10))  
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
    title="Elevation",
    thicknessmode="pixels", thickness=50,
    lenmode="pixels", len=200,
    yanchor="top", y=1,
    ticks="outside", ticksuffix="",
    dtick=5
))
fig.show()
```

[image: Plotly figure]

If you want to use `matplotlib` then you can refer below code.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib as mpl
# from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
from matplotlib import rc, rcParams
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pandas as pd

url ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patel999jay/Bedford_python/master/POINT_DATA_TITLE.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
# df.head() # see dataframe head

# 2D-arrays from DataFrame
x1 = np.linspace(df['x'].min(), df['x'].max(), len(df['x'].unique()))
y1 = np.linspace(df['y'].min(), df['y'].max(), len(df['y'].unique()))

"""
x, y via meshgrid for vectorized evaluation of
2 scalar/vector fields over 2-D grids, given
one-dimensional coordinate arrays x1, x2,..., xn.
"""

x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)

# Interpolate unstructured D-dimensional data.
z2 = griddata((df['x'], df['y']), df['z'], (x2, y2), method='cubic')

# Ready to plot

fig = plt.figure(211,figsize=(15,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=2,
                         height_ratios=[4, 1])

surf = ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z2, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.terrain,
                       linewidth=1, antialiased=False)
ax.view_init(25,-55)

cset = ax.contourf(x2, y2, z2, zdir='z2', offset=-5, cmap=cm.terrain, antialiased=True)

rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 20

rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('axes', linewidth=2)
rc('font', weight='bold')

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.zaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.set_zticks([-70, -50, -30, -10, 10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110])
plt.title(r'\textbf{Bedford Basin Bathymatry}', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{Latitude}', fontsize=20, labelpad= 23)
plt.ylabel(r'\textbf{Longitude}', fontsize=20, labelpad= 20)
ax.set_zlabel(r'\textbf{Elevation}', fontsize=20, labelpad= 10)
```

[image: matplotlib figure]

**P.S.** : Could you please provide minimal reproduceable example of your problem then I can update my answer accordingly. Right now i am using random data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Random data is ok. I use `gridara` as your way. The `griddata`  uses three nearby points to interpolate the target point. It is ok for a 2-d map. When we use it to interpolate the points on a sphere or hemisphere by  latitudes and longitudes,  It is also good for most areas, but not well for the points on the boundary. Because the distance between  the points (0,0) and  (0,360)  is far for 2d map.

Comment: there are different `interpolation` methods that you can use.